# Show/hide button in form

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In my form I want to show a disabled button "Sending..." when the form is posted and hide the original send button.

Then when the form returns success I want to hide the "Sending..." and show the original button again.

By the way, I am using jQuery validation because I am forced to do it in this app.

**HTML**

```
<form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" class="form-grouped" ng-submit="submitContactForm()" default-validate>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Contact</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Your email</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" ng-model="email" name="email" id="email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="message" name="message" id="message" rows="5" required></textarea>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="form-actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Sending..." class="btn btn-default" disabled>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit">
</div>
</form>
```

**AngularJS**

```
//FORM
$scope.submitContactForm = function () {
    if ($("#contactForm").valid()) {
        //show/hide buttons

        $http({
            url: "data/postContact.aspx",
            data: formFactory.fixData({ email: $scope.email, message: $scope.message }),
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
        }).success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.email = "";
            $scope.message = "";
            //show/hide buttons
        }).error(function (err) { "ERR", console.log(err) })

    }
};
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: yes, but how do I write it in this specific case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a $scope variable something like

```
$scope.showSubmit = true';
```

at the top of your submit function :

```
$scope.showSubmit = false;
```

in the success callback

```
$scope.showSubmit = true;
```

then add ng-show="showSubmit" to the submit button and ng-show="!showSubmit" to the sending button

Comment: Actually, it would be safer to reset it to true in a finally callback.

Comment: @JBNizet how is that written?

Comment: @Cathal Thanks for the solution. Exactly what I was after.

Comment: Using finally() rather than success(). https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api

Comment: I don't think $http has a finally callback. You could achieve this maybe by setting the value to true in both callbacks

Comment: Seems you are right @Cathal. finally() generates this error: TypeError: undefined is not a function. Do you mean I should set it in the error callback as well?

Comment: That's up to you depending on the behaviour you want depending on the success or failure of the http request but if you want the button to be visible once the response has completed regardless of outcome set the showSubmit to true in both success and failure callbacks.